# Node.js and Q Promises: How can I hand over parameters in a cleaner way?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coding-style, promise, q

I have some code like this:

```
function example(data){
    asyncFnOne()
        .all([asyncFnTwo(), data])
        .spread(asyncFnThree)
        .done();
};
```

It doesn't matter what those functions do. The problem I have is that I don't know how asyncFnThree can access both data from asyncFnTwo and from the function parameters. The way I solved the problem is not very readable. Is there a recommended way to do this in a clean way?

A second possible soultion would be

```
function example(data){
    asyncFnOne()
        .then(asyncFnTwo)
        .then(function(result){
            asyncFnThree(result, data);
        })
        .done();
    };
};
```

But I think it is even less readable.

Comment: Did you mean `Q.all([asyncFnOne(), data]).spread(asyncFnTwo).done()`? To my knowledge Q promises don't have an `.all()` method, and certainly none that takes callback functions *and* data.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Sorry.

Comment: Notice that your second snippet is quite different, it does wait with calling `asyncFnTwo(…)` for the first promise, and does pass its value, while your first snippet calls `asyncFnTwo()`  immediately and without arguments. Which behaviour do you want?

Comment: Okay, you're right. I want to call asyncFnTwo with the promise value of asyncFnOne as its argument. Do you think the way I do it in the second snipplet is good style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `Q.all` in the desired way you'd have to do the following:

```
function example(data) {
    return Q.all[
        asyncFnOne().then(asyncFnTwo),
        data
    ]).spread(asyncFnThree);
}
```

Or use a variable for the first part of the chain, so that you don't have to stuff everything in one expression and could use `return Q.all([promiseTwo, data])…`.

The alternative way with the closure is totally fine as well, and rather standard. You might as well use any library that offers some kind of partial application, and use that instead of the function expression.

```
function example(data) {
    return asyncFnOne()
    .then(asyncFnTwo)
    .then(asyncFnThree.bind(null, data)); // argument order to asyncFnThree: data, result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables as buffers or create some "middle-man" promises. You can find some good examples here: http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html?utm_source=javascriptweekly&utm_medium=email

Comment: Thanks for the link, I found some interesting stuff there. What do you mean with variables as buffers?